# ¿Como se actualiza un programa en Linux desde la terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, terminal, linux-mint

Estoy en **Linux Mint Cinnamon** y no se como actualizar una aplicacion, en si me gustaria saber como puedo actualizar cualquier aplicacion, pero el motivo de formular esta pregunta es que hoy salio una nueva actualizacion para visual studio code y al momento de darle **actualizar** al pop-up que sale al abrilo me manda a la pagina web a descargar otro .deb

Comment: Faltan datos. ¿Qué mensaje exactamente recibiste? ¿Qué aplicación quieres actualizar?

Comment: existe una serie de programas las cuales no vas a poder actualizar por terminal. Uno de esos es **visual studio code** el cual esta desarrollado en **electron**.

Comment: @fedorqui no es un mensaje, mas bien es un pop-up de visual studio code que dice que la "hay actualizaciones pendiente" al darle clic, me manda a la pagina de visual studio code para que descargue nuevamente el .deb

Comment: @DavElsanto ¿existe alguna otra solucion? mi internet no es muy bueno como para estar descargando todo VC cada vez que se actualiza

Comment: ¿Pero necesitas actualizarlo o no? Si no necesitas actualizarlo cada vez no lo actualices. Si lo tienes que actualizar, vas a tener que desacargarlo tanto si es un deb que te bajas de una web, como si lo descargas por el gestor de paquetes de Linux Mint. Dices que tu conexión es mala, ¿puedes descargarlo en una biblioteca, universidad, wifi abierta cercana...?

Comment: @ordago si necesito actualizarlo, me gusta trabajar con todos mis programas actualizados

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta la pregunta de @ordago, para propósitos personales, el que te guste un programa actualizado puede convertirse en necesidad. Pero en un entorno corporativo o profesional, una actualización se **necesita** cuando soluciona un problema de seguridad, trae una característica necesaria para el negocio, se acaba el soporte requerido para cierta versión o soluciona algun problema de incompatibilidad. "Lo que está estable, se deja estable" he escuchado muchas veces

Answer (score 1):

Si te pide descargar un archivo `.deb` puedes usar:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i <ruta de archivo.deb>
```

para instalarlo después de descargarlo y si hay algún error sobre dependencias que no estén resueltas, entonces corre:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

Si deseas actualizar a la versión más reciente de un programa que tengas en la lista de tus repositorios o instalado, puedes correr:

```
$ sudo apt install --only-upgrade <programa>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sea que actualices un programa via terminal (usando `apt`) o descargando un archivo `.deb`, vas a tener que descargar el contenido de la actualización.

Para poder actualizar VisualStudio Code usando `apt` debes añadir el repositorio correspondiente a la lista de repositorios que consulta `apt`. Las instrucciones para hacerlo estan [aquí (En inglés)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_debian-and-ubuntu-based-distributions).

Nótese que allí menciona que al instalar por primera vez el archivo `.deb`, se instalará el repositorio y las llaves para hacer las actualizaciones siguientes con el administrador de paquetes (`apt`).

---